# Excel - condense multiple rows into a single row of multiple columns

Tags: excel, rows

I'm trying to use Excel to reformat a dataset. The dataset has multiple rows of 'items' per 'id' which I want to shift into a single row of multiple columns of 'items' per each 'id'. In addition, I'd like to be able to have 2 groups of columns for the 'items' - see screenshots. As per the example not every 'id' will have the same number of 'items'.

The dummy data shown here illustrates the requirement:

Original data:
[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXGUR.png)

Required output:
[required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyEHI.png)

I don't know if this is possible via a formula (which may need to reference each 'id' as a window)? Or whether something more complex is required.
I'm not very au fait with VB and whilst have seen some examples, I'm struggling to adapt the code to work on my dataset.
Can anyone guide me to a suitable solution (that I can understand, edit, develop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first prepare your table how you want.

then you can use this formula to get the
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Data!$F$4:$F$38,(Data!$A$4:$A$38=$A4)*(Data!$C$4:$C$38=B$2),""))

[image: Data Sheet]
[image: Output image]

Comment: Saif - many thanks! I've applied the same approach to my working data and it works a treat. I needed to drag the formula down the columns to trigger the array approach (had a few #SPILL errors to contend with too). Hopeful that your method will allow me to build in more subgrouping if I need it.

Comment: @SimonP just so you keep it in mind, #SPILL errors in array function comes only if you are applying it in a table or there is data available in the spill range. Example if you have one more item in the customer ID# 1003 it will show #Spill error. because this customer already have stationary item 6. so if there is 7th stationary item then there is no empty cell left, next cell is item 7 which is under furniture.